# OpenAI gym GuessingGame-v0 possible solutions

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, hidden-markov-models

I have been struggling to solve the GuessingGame-v0 environment which is part of the OpenAI gym.

In the environment each episode a random number within a range is selected and the agent must "guess" what this random number is. The agent is only provided with the observation of whether the guess was too large or too small.

After researching how to frame the problem I think it may be possible to frame the problem as a Hidden Markov Model, but I am unsure of how to do this.

Each episode the randomly selected number changes and because of this I don't know how the model won't have to change each episode as the goal state is continually shifting.

I could not find any resources on the environment or any environments similar to it other than the documentation provided by OpenAI which I did not find useful.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance on how to solve this environment.

Comment: I looked up the challenge and it appears that the goal state is the same within a single game - https://gym.openai.com/envs/GuessingGame-v0/ . If you wanted to frame this as a Markov Model, what test would you do at the end of each guess (besides testing whether the guess was within 1%)?

Comment: I don't know if the problem should/can be framed as a hidden markov model. I am quite sure it is not an MDP so I thought as the observations are like those of a POMDP it may possibly be a HMM. Do you have any suggestions on possible solution methods? Thanks for the response it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have two stop criteria: guessed value is within 1% or 200 time steps are reached. A number is chosen. If the 1% or 200 steps criterion has not yet been met, either the number is too high or it is too low. There is a history of guesses and their corresponding "low" or "high" results. How would you implement this?

Comment: I was considering using a Deep Recurrent Q-Network. However, I was hesitant to begin implementing this potential solution for a few reasons. Firstly, the environment is said to be "easy" by openAI in the documentation and the other toy-text environments can easily be solved using tabular methods so I think I may be overlooking something. Secondly,  as the action taken by the agent is the predicted number I'm not too sure how to structure the possibile actions as I dont want an output layer with as many neurons as possible guesses.

Comment: Have you scribbled down on a piece of paper the information you need after each guess and the action that will be taken as a result of that information? Are you dealing with probabilities <1 after each guess?

Comment: If the agent were to say replicate a binary search, it would need to know all of the previously guessed values to continue to reduce the size of the iterval in which the number lies. The observation of whether or not each guess is too small or too big tells the agent whether or not the number lies in the upper or lower subinterval and I'm assuming guessing the midpoint of this interval is reasonable.

Comment: Why would it need to know all previous values to get the interval?

Comment: Okay I now see that it only requires the endpoints of the current interval. This is so that it doesn't guess lower than a number it has already been told is too small or guess higher than a number that it has already been told is too high.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting this as an answer so people don't have to read through the list of comments.

You need a program that can simply cycle through:

- generate the random number
- agent guesses a number (within the allowable guess range)
- test whether the number is within 1%.
- if the number is within 1%, stop the iteration, maybe print the guess at this point
- if the iteration is at step 200, stop the iteration and maybe produce some out that gives the final guessed number and the fact it is not within 1%
- if not 200 steps or 1%: a) if the number is too high, record the guess and that it is too high, or b) if the number is too low, record the guess and that it is too low. Iterate through that number bound. Repeat until either the 1% or 200 steps criterion is reached.

Another thought for you: do you need a starting low number and a starting high number?

There are a number of ways in which to implement this solution. There is also a range of programming software in which the solution can be implemented. The particular software you use is probably the one with which you are most familiar.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help, I really appreciate it! I am however struggling to see where reinforcement learning is being used in the given algorithm.